# terminate code execution while debugging in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to stop code execution at certain point while debugger is attached in android studio. is there any possibility ? I have checked all available options in debugger tab but could not found any. Thanks.

Comment: you mean my using break points ? those little red dots ? :D

Comment: breakpoints is the solution, but you should know that if you are using multithread only the current thread will be stopped, while the other threads continue running.

Comment: but using that debugging will be stopped. not code execution

Comment: let me explain, i know this. I want to cancel/terminate execution at some point while debugging.

Comment: definitely execution will be stopped if debugger is attached and break point is there. But I want that code should not execute after that.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional breakpoint, just after where you want to stop it for processing. 
hope this helps you out .

Answer (score 0):

You have to set break point where you want to stop execution in android studio on debugger time.
you can do that via click on vertical strip   at starting of line at your code. it make a red dot on that strip.
see the image below

[image: break point screen]

Comment: let me explain, i know this. I want to cancel/terminate execution at this point.

Comment: e.g I want that application do not execute if(bundle!=null) statement. I hope you get it

Comment: for this you have to  make another break point at after that code you want to skip  and when you reach at break point you have to  click on that break point and drag it to next  break point.  //try this i hope i may be helpful to you.  good luck

Comment: means I can take execution to the next break point ?  this way code i which i want to miss will not be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply press stop button(red square) or press ctrl + F2 to stop execution .

But if you are asking about  detaching debugger from program so that app keeps running and debugger is disabled then I am also struggling to get this done in android studio 2.0 . I think, detaching debugger is not supported in this version. Its weird.